# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (unfix)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel

**My Error:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_name`.`inpatients`, CONSTRAINT `inpatients_ward_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ward_id`) REFERENCES `wards` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `inpatients` (`patient_id`, `ward_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2010101, 06, 2020-10-14 06:44:12, 2020-10-14 06:44:12))
```

**My inpatient table is here:**

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('patient_id');
$table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
$table->char('discharged',4)->default('NO'); // YES | NO
$table->unsignedBigInteger('ward_id');
$table->foreign('ward_id')->references('id')->on('wards');
```

**inpatientController**

```
$INPtable = new inpatient;
$INPtable->patient_id = $request->reg_pid;
$INPtable->ward_id = $request->reg_ipwardno;
```

**Inpatient Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
'ward_id','patient_id',
];

public function ward() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ward');
}

public function patient() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patients');
}
```

I don't understand what's going wrong here. Please help me.

Comment: is there a ward with id `06`?

Comment: I think I have got my problems. basically the id is not ward id it's the number of wards. Maybe this the problem. Thank for your suggestion, let me try first.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Thanks a lot @lagbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ward table has ward_no also. I have passed ward_no instead of ward id. That's why the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error will be mostly because of the table which you referred as foreign key in inpatient table i.e ward table. You first have to enter data in the ward table, and that data you can refer in the child table. If key 6, is not present in the ward table, insert it first into the table, then do the insertion in the inpatient table.
Hope you got it. Thank You :)

Comment: My ward table has ward_no also. I have passed ward_no instead of ward id. That's why the error.